# PostgreSQL update data error in excluded.column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.5

i try update data from another table using PostgreSQL 9.6 following the document and stackoverflow advice with this query

**1.** this query is for finding the id_vertex of geom  that close to `lokasi_esb.geom`. You can ignore this one, it works properly

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 AS 
WITH kuery2 as(
    SELECT id_esb, id_vertex, distant, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id_esb ORDER BY distant asc) as ranked FROM table vertex)
select id_esb, id_vertex, distant, ranked
from kuery2 
where ranked=1;
```

**2.** this query to update the lokasi_esb table with id_vertex_nearest column **without** `excluded` table. ////i already know it's wrong and i update on the number 3

```
INSERT INTO lokasi_esb(id_esb, id_vertex_nearest) 
select id_esb,id_vertex 
from temp1
ON CONFLICT (id_esb) DO UPDATE
SET lokasi_esb.id_vertex_nearest = temp1.id_vertex;
```

i got this error

**ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table « temp1 » 

SQL state: 42P01

Character: 634**

**3.** this query to update the lokasi_esb table with id_vertex_nearest column **with** `excluded` table

```
INSERT INTO lokasi_esb(id_esb, id_vertex_nearest) 
select id_esb,id_vertex 
from temp1
ON CONFLICT (id_esb) DO UPDATE
SET lokasi_esb.id_vertex_nearest = excluded.id_vertex;
```

igot this error(transleted from indonesia)

**ERROR:  column excluded.id_vertex not yet exist 

SQL state: 42703 

Character: 634**

So can anybody can help me figure out what happened here?

Comment: Should be `excluded.id_vertex_nearest` that is the field being inserted into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column names from the "excluded" record refer to the columns of the target table. And the target column in the SET expression must not be prefixed with the table name (because you can't update a different table anyway)

So you need to use:

```
SET id_vertex_nearest = excluded.id_vertex_nearest
```